# is location detection required google play services android studio

Tags: android, google-play-services, currentlocation

I have built an app using location detection to get the current location
I am using LocationManager and LocationLiastener

the app works fine but when I tried to run it on advice without android play service it won't get the current Location and show the following dialog
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sYBa.png)

this is the app link on Github
https://github.com/mostafa-n3ma/Pcm-helper1.0

Comment: [No, it's not](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+location+without+google+play+services&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS989US989&oq=android+location+without+g&aqs=chrome.0.0i20i263i512j0i512j69i57j0i22i30l2j0i390l3.4670j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). You're using the wrong dependencies.

Comment: I am using it when I check whether the  location settings are enabled or not 
by calling LocationRequest from that library
so whenever I run it on a device with no google services the 
the Location Update request is not triggered 
I will use a different ways to check Location settings 
thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the problem

```
    private fun checkDeviceLocationSettingsAndGetLocationUpdates(resolve: Boolean = true) {
    val locationRequest = com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest.create().apply {
        priority = LocationRequest.QUALITY_LOW_POWER
    }
    val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest)

    val settingsClint = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(requireActivity())
    val locationSettingsResponseTask = settingsClint.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())

    locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnFailureListener { exeption ->
        if (exeption is ResolvableApiException && resolve) {
            try {
                startIntentSenderForResult(
                    exeption.resolution.intentSender,
                    REQUEST_TURN_DEVICE_LOCATION_ON,
                    null,
                    0, 0, 0,
                    null
                )
            } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error geting location settings resolution: " + sendEx.message)
            }
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(
                this.requireView(),
                "Location services must be enabled to use the app", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
            ).setAction(android.R.string.ok) {
                checkDeviceLocationSettingsAndGetLocationUpdates()
            }.show()
        }

    }

    locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0.0f, locationListener
            )

        }
    }
   

}
```

I am using the google services library to check Location setting if it was enabled or not
if the location is ON the location update request will be triggered

else it will ask the user to enable it and then trigger the location update request

if the services are not available nothing will happen and no location update will be requested

so I will try another way to check the location feature

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/gavingt/SunCalculator/blob/8d99560ce6b4888488a1b500f7f3ab3193aaeef8/app/src/main/java/com/gavinsappcreations/sunrisesunsettimes/utilities/utils.kt#L99) for how to check whether location is enabled without Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

By checking your code here https://github.com/mostafa-n3ma/Pcm-helper1.0/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L69

Are you sure you are not dependent on the google play service library?

Comment: sorry I am using the library when I check the Location Settings if the location is enabled or not 
and I will direct the user to enable it 
in the method 
checkDeviceLocationSettingsAndGetLocationUpdates()

in the fragment that deals with current Location